# Old Backbone & Marionette built with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, backbone.js, marionette, webpack-dev-server

#### Description

I'm trying to add "webpack" build to an old project with backbone and marionette.

Im getting an error

```
backbone.marionette.js:3228 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'radio' of undefined
    at constructor._initChannel (backbone.marionette.js:3228)
    at new constructor (backbone.marionette.js:3096)
    at eval (tzook.js:128)
    at Object../frontend-app/tzook.js (main.bundle.js:7754)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.bundle.js:79)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_(:3000/webpack)-dev-server/client?:2:18)
    at Object.0 (main.bundle.js:9043)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.bundle.js:79)
    at checkDeferredModules (main.bundle.js:46)
    at main.bundle.js:152
```

so I have tried doing:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
    babysitter = require('backbone.babysitter'),
    wreqr = require('backbone.wreqr');
Backbone.Wreqr = wreqr;
```

but as I can see in the `backbone.marionette.js` file.
It doesn't matter if I load my own backbone, as it load its own version :/

Versions:

```
"backbone": "1.2.3",
    "backbone-forms": "0.14.0",
    "backbone.marionette": "^2.4.4",
    "backbone.paginator": "~2.0.2",
    "backbone.subroute": "^0.4.4",
    "backbone.wreqr": "^1.0.0",



(function(root, factory) {

  if (true) {
    !(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [__webpack_require__(/*! backbone */ "./node_modules/backbone.marionette/node_modules/backbone/backbone.js"), __webpack_require__(/*! underscore */ "./node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"), __webpack_require__(/*! backbone.wreqr */ "./node_modules/backbone.wreqr/lib/backbone.wreqr.js"), __webpack_require__(/*! backbone.babysitter */ "./node_modules/backbone.babysitter/lib/backbone.babysitter.js")], __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ = (function(Backbone, _) {
      return (root.Marionette = root.Mn = factory(root, Backbone, _));
    }).apply(exports, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__),
                __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ !== undefined && (module.exports = __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__));
  } else { var BabySitter, Wreqr, _, Backbone; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Notice: In the next major release of Marionette, v3, Wreqr will be swapped for an updated library, Radio.

You need to include [backbone.radio](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/backbone.radio.html) as a dependency before marionette